# Proper way to set up apache2 default config and htaccess in project directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, redirect

Dear people,

**My goal** is to set up the apache2's `000-default.conf` and the `.htaccess` in a specific way, so the user will always be redirected to a specific php file (`index.php` for example) if they (the user) wants to access the web app, which I am building.

Examples :

- example-app.local
- example-app.local/hello-world
- example-app.local/admin.php
- example-app-local/../../../../my-passwords.txt

All of them should point to `index.php`. I followed several tutorials, but I guess I need a specific tutorial for me, so that I can fully understand the concepts of apache2 and its configurations. Feel free to judge me - I am alright with criticism.

**What I have in my files** is the following

*1. The 000-default.conf file which is located in /etc/apache2/sites-available/*

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   <Directory /var/www/>
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny
       allow from all
   </Directory>

   ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
   DocumentRoot /var/www
   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

*...and loads of comments*

*2. The example-app.local.conf file which is located in /etc/apache2/sites-available/*

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin admin@example.com
   ServerName example-app.local
   ServerAlias www.example-app.local
   DocumentRoot "/var/www/example-app"
   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

*3. The .htaccess file which is located in /var/www/example-app/*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [QSA,R]
```

**What I get** is the following : "Apache default conf is like a god of the configurations and you can state specifically that you can `AllowRedirect` which will magically trigger the functionality of `htaccess` and there you need the even more magical syntax to make every request from the user point ONLY to the index.php" Is this correct?

**What is working** Apache is working. I am enabling and disabling configs via

```
 sudo a2ensite 000-default.conf
 sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf
```

and then I restart and check that everything is fine via

```
sudo service apache2 restart
sudo service apache2 status
```

the status states `active (running)`.

The content of `/etc/hosts` is also edited in a correct way, because I can actually see the content of the `index.html` file when I try to point my browser to the `example-app.local` page. I would also like to point out that I have php installed correctly - I tested it via the `phpinfo` function/method.

I tried several tutorials and none of them helped me. I believe I am missing something important and I am too 'blind' to see it, so I need someone to 'open' my eyes, so please - help me.

Best regards,

Yet another confused startup developer,

Bobkoo

Answer (score 0):

Try tis one:
After `RewriteEngine On` try `RewriteBase /` and lose the slash before index.php

BTW you working on Windows... so the `DocumentRoot "/var/www/example-app"` should be something like `C:\xampp\htdocs\project-folder`

Comment: Hey, thank you for the proposal. I tried adding the `Rewrite Base /` and removing the slash. I am still receiving the index.html page rather than the index.php . My current code looks like :

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ info.php?url=$1 [QSA,R]